# Find how many bytes are ready to be read from a FILE* or a file descriptor

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor

Given a `FILE*` or a file descriptor, is there a standard way to tell how many bytes are ready to be read?

I can't use `s=ftell(f),fseek(f,0,SEEK_END),e=ftell(f),fseek(f,s,SEEK_SET),e-s` since the `FILE*` is just wrapping a file descriptor I got from [`pipe(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), and I get `ESPIPE` when I try that.

I was thinking of using `select(2)` with a zero timeout to tell that I have at least one byte ready to be read, and then reading a byte at a time until the `select(2)` told me to stop.  This seems kinda clunky and slow though .

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read` can return fewer bytes than you asked for, and must do so if data is available, but it would need to block in order to fill the buffer.

So the usual thing is to use `select` to detect readable, then read whatever your favoured buffer size is. Alternatively, set O_NONBLOCK using fcntl, and check for -1 return value and errno EAGAIN.

Comment: Generally, I prefer reading prearranged sizes, but I'm writing a test, and I want to make sure that the amount ready at a certain part is what I want.

Comment: @rampion: ah right. But you said you were thinking of reading one byte at a time with a call to `select` with zero timeout. This is an improvement on that, rather than addressing the initial premise of the question.

Answer (score 5):

It's not blessed by any modern standards, but a common traditional unix way to do this is with `ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &n);` See the answers to this question:

[Determine the size of a pipe without calling read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820/determine-the-size-of-a-pipe-without-calling-read)

Answer (score 4):

If you're only looking for something more efficient that 1 byte reads, and not the size of the available data on the FIFO, then you can:

1. Set the file descriptor to non blocking mode.
2. Use `select` to know when data is available
3. Call `read` with a large buffer. It might return less than you requested (*check the return code*), or it might return -1 with `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` to indicate you should go back to calling `select` (no data is availabe)

Answer (score 1):

Extending on the answer given by R..

A large real-world [software framework](https://github.com/qt) uses ioctl to find out the number of bytes like this (discounting error checks):

**FreeBSD, Linux, and Solaris** ([source](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/0a2f2382541424726168804be2c90b91381608c6/src/qt3support/network/q3socketdevice_unix.cpp#L559)):

```
int nbytes;
ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &nbytes);
```

**IRIX** ([source](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/0a2f2382541424726168804be2c90b91381608c6/src/qt3support/network/q3socketdevice_unix.cpp#L559)):

```
size_t nbytes;
ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &nbytes);
```

**Windows** ([source](https://github.com/qt/qtwebengine-chromium/blob/b45f07bfbe74c333f1017810c2409e1aa6077a1b/chromium/third_party/libevent/buffer.c#L343)):

```
long nbytes;
ioctlsocket(fd, FIONREAD, &nbytes);
```

Comment: Chillingly, the man page for ioctl(2) says: " Some generic ioctls are not implemented for all types of file descriptors.  These include: ... FIONREAD.  I suspect "(discounting error checks)" covers more ground than might be immediately apparent! Have a backup plan if you go this way.

Answer (score 0):

doy.  [`fstat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).  I glanced at it earlier, and saw it wouldn't work on `FILE*`, (which is why I fell back to the `fseek` anti-pattern), but didn't think to fall back on the file descriptor.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I'm pretty sure `fstat` will always return 0 in the `st_size` field for a FIFO.

Comment: Yup, it works.  And it's a [pipe(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), not a [fifo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo).  Looks like this [isn't portable, though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820/determine-the-size-of-a-pipe-without-calling-read/71925#71925).